# How to unset/destroy all session data except some specific keys?

Tags: php, session

I have some session data in a website. I want to destroy all session data when user click another page, except some specific keys like `$_SESSION['x']` and `$_SESSION['y']`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You mean other users' sessions?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You want to keep $_SESSION['x'] and $_SESSION['y']?

Comment: yes i want keep x and y only.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe do something like this

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val)
{

    if ($key !== 'somekey')
    {

      unset($_SESSION[$key]);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

to unset a particular session variable use.

```
unset($_SESSION['one']);
```

to destroy all session variables at one use.

`session_destroy()`

To free all session variables use.

`session_unset();`

if you want to destroy all Session variable except `x` and `y` you can do something like this.

```
$requiredSessionVar = array('x','y');
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    if(!in_array($key, $requiredSessionVar)) {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Benjamin: you can iterate over the variables in a session.

Answer (score 3):

As `$_SESSION` is a regular array, you can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) to get your resulting array:

```
$keys = array('x', 'y');
$_SESSION = array_intersect_key($_SESSION, array_flip($keys));
```

Here [`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip) is used to flip the key/value association of `$keys` and `array_intersect_key` is used to get the intersection of both arrays while using the keys for comparison.

Comment: Thanks @Gumbo,

This helps too. But the easiest one is above for rookies. Thx again.

Answer (score 2):

Will this help?

```
function unsetExcept($keys) {
  foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value)
    if (!in_array($key, $keys))
      unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is. But i was searching a spesific function in Session Functions. Thanks, i will do this way. Also thanks @Kemal Fadillah for original loop.

Answer (score -2):

So when i can't ask i will answer:

This question is old but still someone is reviewing this like me i searched and i liked one of the answers but here is a better one: Lets unset $array1 except some variables as $array2

```
function unsetExcept($array1,$array2) {
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
        if(!in_array($key, $array2)){
            unset($array1[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this better ? IT'S NOT ONLY FOR $_SESSION