# how to unset session variables with a certain prefix

Tags: php, session-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to unset/destroy all session data except some specific keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214369/how-to-unset-destroy-all-session-data-except-some-specific-keys)

I am having certain session variables starting with "cars"
such as

```
$_SESSION["cars_registration"];
$_SESSION["cars_make"];
$_SESSION["cars_model"];
$_SESSION["cars_variant"];
.
.
.
$_SESSION["cars_date_created"];
```

I want to know the code for unsetting / deleting / emptying only those session variables which starts with cars as prefix like above.

So far I have achieved this but dont have any idea about code for unsetting them.

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value)
{
    if (strpos($key, 'cars_') === 0)
    {
      // Need to delete / unset the session variables  
    }
}
```

Please help me with it

Comment: Whats's wrong with `unset($_SESSION[$key])` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you almost got it!!!

```
 foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value)
    {
        if (strpos($key, 'cars_') === 0)
        {
          unset($_SESSION[$key]); //add this line
        }
    }
```

here are some few explanations. inside the `foreach` you set `$key` to be a variable to hold the `key` of the `$_SESSION` array for each iteration and it works the same with the `$value`

reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: There is a good reason for using `===`. `strpos` returns `FALSE` if needle was not found. `strpos('cats_registration', 'cars_')` will return `FALSE` and `FALSE == 0` and the key be removed when it should not.

Comment: @SalmanA just revised my answer thank you

Comment: @Mahan - thnks for the help buddy

Answer (score 6):

Well, I'm glad to see that [php](/questions/tagged/php) is still capable of ignoring the glaringly obvious.

There are many ways that you can do this with loops and all sorts of things, however the *right* way to do this would be to use a sub array `cars`, which you can easily destroy in one go.

So instead of creating

```
$_SESSION["cars_registration"];
$_SESSION["cars_make"];
```

etc, you would create:

```
$_SESSION["cars"]["registration"];
$_SESSION["cars"]["make"];
```

So when you come to unset it, you simply need to do:

```
unset($_SESSION["cars"]);
```

`$_SESSION` can hold data in a multi-dimensional structure just like any other array - it does not need to be a flat collection of values.

Comment: +1, I was thinking just this, why not make cars an array.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `unset`.

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value)
{
    if (strpos($key, 'cars_') === 0)
    {
      unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**session_unregister** — Unregister a global variable from the current session
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

**session_unset** — Free all session variables
Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal.

**session_destroy** — Destroys all data registered to a session

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, you can use [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to 'destroy' a variable. So, once you're convinced the key meets your criteria you can do:

```
unset($_SESSION($key));
```