# PHP: unset $_SESSION of array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unset

I have a session of arrays named:

```
$_SESSION['A'];
```

it contains

```
$_SESSION['A'][0] = 'A';
$_SESSION['A'][1] = 'B';
```

I can unset the **$_SESSION['A'];** using

```
unset($_SESSION['A']);
```

it unset all the value in the array how can I unset all value stored in

```
$_SESSION['A'];
```

exept

```
$_SESSION['A'][0];
$_SESSION['A'][1];
```

I've seen this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214369/how-to-unset-destroy-all-session-data-except-some-specific-keys)

which it unset all **$_SESSION** exept some stored in array. I used this code to unset it on array but I don't know how to used it as arrays.

```
$keys = array('x', 'y');
$_SESSION = array_intersect_key($_SESSION, array_flip($keys));
```

Comment: Loop through it using a `for` loop and unset the values manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) like this:

```
$_SESSION['A'] = array_slice($_SESSION['A'], 0, 2);
```

**Update:**

Also, for non sequential indexes we can create this function:

```
  function array_pick($picks, $array)
    {
     $temp = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if(in_array($key, $picks))
            {
                $temp[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
     return array_values($temp);// or just $temp to keep original indexes
    }
```

[PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0fx-n6c)

Comment: Good idea! But you forgot to place the values back in the session variable. This solution also doesn't handle cases where the indexes are not sequential. How would you solve it for indexes 3 and 7?

Comment: @Lix - adding a function such as `array_pick` to someone's library would be a good fix right?!

Comment: @Lix - that's why I attached a fiddle ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$keys = array(0,1);
$_SESSION['A'] = array_intersect_key($_SESSION['A'], array_flip($keys));
```

And [here's the proof of concept](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rgd-srm).

Comment: Shouldn't "*// remove keys 0 and 1*" be "*// remove anything but keys 0 and 1*"?

Comment: @h2ooooooo: You're right, it's just a typo in the fiddle... sorry! Works, nevertheless.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: Nah, merely fixed the last piece of code from the OP's question... There are other things I'm a lot more proud of ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do unset only certain values in an array. Rather, just save the values of those variables, unset the entire array and then reset the values.

```
// Save existing values
$saved_var1 = $_SESSION["A"][0];
$saved_var2 = $_SESSION["A"][1];

// Unset the entire array
unset( $_SESSION["A"] );

// Set the values by the saved variables
$_SESSION["A"] = array(
  $saved_var1,
  $saved_var2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
$_SESSION['A']=array_splice($_SESSION['A'], 2);
```

Comment: Again, a nice idea... but what if the indexes are not sequential? `$_SESSION["A"][4]` and `$_SESSION["A"][2]`?

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
$_SESSION['A'] = array();
unset($_SESSION['A']);
```

Comment: Yea - but what does it do? It destroys the entire array. This is not what the question was asking for at all...